# URL Query String Variable Count in PHP

Tags: string, url, variables, count

I am developing an accounting software as project. I want to count sets of variables in URL query string. eg

http://localhost/xampp/khata2/test/tableaddrow_nw.php?*accname1=1&DrAmount1=1&CrAmount1=1&accname2=2+was2&DrAmount2=2&CrAmount2=2&accname3=3+was3&DrAmount3=3&CrAmount3=3&accname4=4+was4&DrAmount4=4&CrAmount4=4&accname5=5+was5&DrAmount5=5&CrAmount5=5&accname6=6+was6&DrAmount6=6&CrAmount6=6*

There is a set of kind of rows in a query string accname1,DrAmount1,CrAmount1 .... accname6,DrAmount6,CrAmount6 so on which is generated dynamicaly as user inputs data in rows.
how can i find out ho many rows are (set of data) are in query string ?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$rows = explode("&", $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

This will give you an array of:

```
accname1=1
DrAmount1=1
CrAmount1=1
```

So you could get the total as `count($rows)`.

Is this what you meant?